# IntelliJ windows from Linux box displayed via ssh/X11 on MacOS illegible

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, xorg, xquartz

I have XQuartz 1.20.11 (xorg-server 1.20.11) on an M1 MacBook Pro (installed via MacPorts) and am trying to display IntelliJ running on a Linux box via ssh/X11.

The IntelliJ windows appear with oddly rendered text that's unreadable—the white background turns black, and there are white outlines around the black text. If I click outside of an X11 window and start typing, then the IntelliJ window looks normal. But as soon as I touch the trackpad, IntelliJ becomes unreadable.

I tried taking a screen shot, but it comes out looking normal even though the window is nearly unreadable. So I've attached photo of the screen.

X11 windows from other applications display fine.

As mentioned in an [XQuartz thread](https://github.com/XQuartz/XQuartz/issues/31), setting
`export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dsun.java2d.xrender=false'` clears up the text but results in extremely slow display.

Anyone have suggestions for troubleshooting or a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-227639/Menu-rendering-on-external-monitor-is-broken-with-XQuartz) for this issue in IDEA tracker, please upvote it and follow  for updates.
Do [the latest recommendations](https://github.com/XQuartz/XQuartz/issues/31#issuecomment-1356657794) from the thread that you mentioned help?
If not, then please [try switching IDE boot JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html) to e.g. [OpenJDK 17](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java17) and inform if the issue persists after that.